# What the best way to handle project level variables in perl

Tags: perl, oop

I was asked to look into switching a bunch of ksh scripts into perl. Right now all the system variables are exported from a common file (urls, database usernames, etc).

My question is in perl what is the best way to handle these variables?

PS. I like the idea of using a ini file but then I need a ini file reading library (which people here wont like).

Comment: Config::Any will happily use INI files (and many other common formats), and will keep people here happy. ;)

Comment: Or if you prefer, use [Config::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/Config::Tiny) to read `.ini` formatted files.

Comment: @Bill: If your company has an aversion to config modules then it is hard to guess what options you have available. You could put `Config/Tiny.pm` into your program directory and tell them you wrote it yourself! Otherwise I recommend a Perl module, say `MyConfig.pm` that subclasses `Exporter` and exports all the constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on my comment, here is an example config module `MyConfig.pm` that exports two constants.

```
package MyConfig;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Exporter';

our @EXPORT = ( qw/ URL USERNAME / );

use constant URL => 'http:/domain.com/';
use constant USERNAME => 'myuser';

1;
```

and a program file that uses it

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use MyConfig;

print URL, "\n";
print USERNAME, "\n";
```

**output**

```
http:/domain.com/
myuser
```

If you read the [documentation on `Exporter`](https://metacpan.org/module/Exporter) you will see how to use `@EXPORT_OK` and `%EXPORT_TAGS` to categorize the constants and avoid polluting the calling package's namespace too much.

Comment: This looks like a lot of namespace pollution.

Comment: @daotoad: as little or as much as you like. You can choose to import everything, or import nothing at all and refer to the values as `MyConfig::URL` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a similar concept to what your ksh scripts have.

Create a common package file with all the settings in them as package `our` variables.
e.g. `ProjConfig.pm` contains

```
package ProjConfig;

use strict;
use warnings;

our $BaseUrl = 'http://www.fred.com/';
our $DbName = 'TheDB';

1;
```

Then your calling code simply refers to these variables with a qualified name.
e.g. `program.pl` contains

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use ProjConfig;

{
    my $db = someConnectFunction( $ProjConfig::DbName );
    # do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a config file and read it in whenever you need.

```
use Config::Merge;

my $config = Config::Merge->new ( '/path/to/config_file.yml' );

my $file = $config->C('filename');
```

That will read in a yaml config file which will result in the yaml
structure being available as a perl hash.

The yaml file could be something like:

```
db:
  name: db_name
  url : 192.168.1.1
```

Back in the file:

```
print $file->{db}{name}  would print out 'db_name'.
```